# Ansible - Read subkey from dict entries and concat to string

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I'm pretty new to Ansible, coming from Puppet I really like it.
I'm trying to get a string compiled from server admin_port.

Vars file:

```
webservers:
  ws1:
    listen_address: "webserver1.mydomain"
    admin_port: "7779"
    http_port: "7777"
    ssl_port: "4443"
  ws2:
    listen_address: "webserver2.mydomain"
    admin_port: "7779"
    http_port: "7777"
    ssl_port: "4443"
```

I'm templating quite a customised set of config files so I'm trying to get the two listen ports into this format:

```
ports=7779,7779
```

I've tried:

```
vars:    
  webserver_admin_ports: "{{lookup('subelements', webservers, 'admin_port', {'skip_missing': True})}}"
```

But I run into the issue:

```
Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: the key admin_port should point to a list, got '7779'"}
```

I'm sure this isn't too tricky and the data structure is simple enough, there could be 1 or 10 servers.

In Puppet I'd do this in the template, but it seems with ansible its better to pass a var.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar question, this is my solution.
In the template, do the lookup, it keeps the code cleaner:

```
{%- set serverNames = [] -%}
{%- set adminPorts = [] -%}
{%- set listenAddresses = [] -%}
{%- set httpPorts = [] -%}
{%- for server in webserver_meta -%}
  {{- serverNames.append(server) -}}
  {{- adminPorts.append(webserver_meta[server].admin_port) -}}
  {{- listenAddresses.append(webserver_meta[server].listen_address) -}}
  {{- httpPorts.append(webserver_meta[server].http_port) -}}
{%- endfor %}
serverNames={{ serverNames|join(',') }}
serverAdminPorts={{ adminPorts|join(',') }}
serverListenAddress={{ listenAddresses|join(',') }}
serverHttpPorts={{ httpPorts|join(',') }}
```